# How to find eigen vector for an eigen value in generalized eigen value problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a generalised eigen value problem of the form $A$x = λ$B$x. I have computed the eigen value (say λ1) I am interested in using Eigen library(C++). However, because the library does not support eigen vector generation for a generalized eigen value problem I need to compute the corresponding eigen vector of the eigen value λ1. What is the mathematical process for doing the above?

Comment: A quick google and you will find a lot of tutorials on how to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Knowing $\lambda$ though solving the simultaneous equations arising from $(A-\lambda B)x = 0$ will give you the eigenvectors.

Comment: You might either ask [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigen) or use directly the [DGGEV](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dggev.f) LAPACK function (or a suitable variant depending on the structure of $A$ and/or $B$).